# How would I go about adding a json datasource to Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am pretty new to .NET and come from a mainly LAMP background. My goal is to sync content via API (already in place) that I have access to that provides data via JSON.

I have set up all of the proper data types on the Umbraco side but now I'm not so sure how to go about setting up an external data source to connect the api and the Umbraco back-office.

I have started building an API client in .net MVC outside of Umbraco but want some guidance on how to connect the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umbraco has its own web api implementation that gives easy access to Umbraco objects. If you are wanting to serve data from the CMS as json then you should build your api here. It is basically a wrapper for the .net web api and works in the same way so you can define your objects and the web api will look after the serialisation into json.

Read more here.https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

Comment: Thanks, but this is the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I want to import data into Umbraco from an external service that now holds content via json api client. I want to be able to set up doc types in Umbraco and then have a sync from the external service API to the Umbraco backoffice and have it populate Umbraco with the nodes so they mirror what is in the API system.

Comment: Then you will need to use the publishing events in the api

Comment: In fact ignore last. Sorry.  You will need to use the ContentService api to create or update content items and populate them with data from your api.